# Steganography using the DCT

Tags: java, text, jpeg, steganography, dct

Broadly speaking there are 4 steps involved in embedding a message using DCT:

1. Divide the image into 8x8 blocks
2. Transform each block using DCT mathematical operations
3. Quantitize each DCT block (lossy compression)
4. Embed the message bits from the quantitized coefficients (avoid 0, 1, -1, and the AC)

Thats ok, but I am not sure how to extract the data back out. Are you suppose to go through steps 1-3 to quantitize each block in order to extract the LSB of each coefficient?

If that's the case, would you not be losing (possible the embedded data) data because it is a lossy technique?

Also when I tried to quantitize each block, I am left with the same coefficients from the previous image (as in the LSB change had no effect) ??

Could someone enlighten me on this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embedding of the message occurs after the lossy compression -- there's no possibility of losing the message, because the steps which lose data have already been performed (other than the actual embedding, which loses only image data, replacing it with your message). Ideally you then extract the message directly from the coefficients themselves -- that is, decompression is not involved in the extraction.

Comment: Do you mean to just transform each block, and then extract it's LSB. Thus do not quantitize them?

Comment: The quantization happens because JPEG compression requires quantization. There isn't any LSB extraction on the encoding side -- it's LSB replacement.

Comment: OK, so just to clear it up. You embed in the quantitized coefficents (step 3), and then extract the DCT coeffs (only to step 2) ? Thanks again (Just that I wouldn't of thought that quantitised coeffs would have the same LSB to the dequantized coeffs)

Comment: I think there's still some confusion here. Steps 1-4 are only involved in embedding the message, and steps 1-3 are just basic JPEG compression. That is, you do completely standard JPEG compression, and then you do steganography on the *already DCT'ed image*. And then, on the receiving end, you extract the message from the JPEG coefficients themselves. That is, the extraction process doesn't need to do any sort of DCT stuff. It just reads bits.

Comment: Ahh. See what I am currently doing is, after all steps I then dequantitize each block, and then apply the inverse DCT to bring back the pixel data which is then stored as pixels. Is that not the correct way? Because in the receiving end, the stego'd image is then transformed to DCT coeffs to do extracting ( but that now seems to be wrong). Sorry about all this confusion

Comment: Ah, I see. I mean, that can still work, but of course you'll want to skip the quantization step on both ends -- if you're transferring raw pixel data there's no reason to lose information you don't have to. I could see quantization (on the encoding side, not the extraction side) being useful if you were then going through a JPEG compression step you had no control over, but otherwise it's extraneous.

Comment: OK, that's cleared up. Just one more question, if you know Java, is there a bufferedImage steam that can take the quantitized coeffs in order to store the data compressed? Because I am using setRGB() to store the pixel data. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of any help there. It's been years since I made any significant use of Java. It's unlikely that one exists in the standard library, since there's also a (lossless) compression step *after* the DCT and quantization -- it would be of no use other than for steganography. If you want to go that route, you'll probably need to construct the JPEG data yourself.

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply DCT block back by quantization matrix, you would most probably get very big numbers for big spatial frequencies - picture would become noisy. But then you need to normalize the coefficients, so that any value of any pixel does not exceed [0..1] bounds ( [0..255] ) After normalization you could loose some info.

Comment: How do you mean by normalizing the coefficients?

Comment: @DouglasGrealis, by returning back to image while in floating-point numbers, normalizing all pixels to bounds and then re-encoding to JPEG.